# seg faulting textbuffer newTB

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

when I run my program, it seems to have a segmentation fault somewhere however I've run tests and it seems I cannot find where it is. I'm using gcc -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -O to compile.

The task is to create a textbuffer in TB newTB that separates by "\n" and puts it in a linked list.

```
test = newTB("hello\ngood bye\nworld\n");
[hello]->[good bye]->[world]
```

This is currently the only function at the moment so it has to be something I've missed that's causing it to seg fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "textbuffer.h"

struct textbuffer {
    char *text;
    int length;
    TB next;
};

void printBuffer(TB tb);

TB newTB (char text[]){
    if (text == NULL) {
        printf("buffer underflow\n");
        abort();
    }

    TB new = calloc(1, sizeof(struct textbuffer));
    new->length = 0;
    new->next = NULL;
    TB current = new;

    char *token;
    int size;

    //first token; intialise first.
    token = strtok(text, "\n");
    size = strlen(token);
    current->text = calloc(size + 1, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(current->text, token);
    //use memset to add a NULL terminator at the end.
    memset(current->text, '\0', size + 1);
    new->length++;
    current->next = NULL;



    int count = 0;
    while (token != NULL) {
        //first linked list already done, do nothing for the first loop.
        if (count == 0) {

        } else {
            //create next textbuffer and fill it with the token.
            current->next = calloc(1, sizeof(struct textbuffer));
            current = current->next;
            size = strlen(token);
            current->text = calloc(size + 1, sizeof(char));
            strcpy(current->text, token);
            memset(current->text, '\0', size + 1);

            new->length++;
        }

        count++;
        token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }

    current->next = NULL;


    return new;
}
```

Comment: Use `malloc` instead of `calloc` there as you're initializing it anyway.

Comment: `memset(current->text, '\0', size + 1);` sets the entire string to zero. Not what you want. You can remove that, `strcpy` does it already (I'd have used `strdup`)

Comment: Build a debug version (drop the `-O` flag and add the `-g` flag when building), and [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Does strcpy automatically add a '\0' to the end of the string? I assumed it didn't so I was using memset haha. Now i realise my mistake lol.

Comment: don't use `new` as a variable name... just in case you drop this C crap for a real language like C++  :)

Comment: A string is always terminated by `\0`. Otherwise it's not a string. As `strcpy` copies strings, it must copy including `\0`. It doesn't "add" it. It is already there in the source string and is copied.

Comment: Try running under Valgrind or compile with `-g` and run it under GDB or LLDB.  You will instantly know where your problem is.

Comment: yes but with the "hello\ngoobye\nworld\n\" the '\0' is at the end. thus 
"hello" and "goobye" must be terminated by '\0' since the strcpy doesn't copy the '\0' until the last linked list.

Comment: @lkal when you call `strtok` it returns a valid string complete with `\0` at the end - if it didn't you wouldn't be able to call `strlen` on them

Comment: Oh so there was no need to independently add the '\0'. Thank you so much!

I have another question; for the last linked list, if strcpy copies the '\0' as well, does strtok also add an additional '\0'?

Comment: What is "TB"? Some icky typedef hiding a pointer?

Comment: TB is just a pointer to the struct textbuffer

Comment: the function: `strtok()` actually modifies the source string by replacing the delimiter character with a NUL byte

Comment: Suggest reading/understanding the MAN pages for each system function you are using.  (your comments verify that you currently do not understand the details of the system functions you are using.

Comment: Do NOT hide pointers via `typedef` statements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the strtok function.
As described in this post:
[C's strtok() and read only string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272876/cs-strtok-and-read-only-string-literals)
The strtok function is not working for string literals since it changes the string.
Just try:

```
char str[] = "hello\ngood bye\nworld\n";
test = newTB(str);
```