# how do I remove the substring of a String in C

Tags: c

I am having hard time getting the substring of a string in C. For example if I have a

```
char *buff = "cat –v <  x y z | ";
char *p = strtok (buff, " ");
while (p != NULL)
{
    if (!strcmp(p, "<") && !isredirected)
    {
        isredirected = 1;
        infileindex  = tokenscounter + 1;
        inputredirectionindex = tokenscounter;
    }
    commandsArray[tokenscounter++]  = p;
    p = strtok (NULL, " ");

}
```

from this buff string, I would like to remove any string that is between **'<'** and **'|'**. that is removing x y z . I used strtok to parse all the tokens, but cannot get to remove that x y z.  After I find **'<'** I want to get rid of all the tokens that come after **<** and before **|**

Comment: What result do you expect and what did you actually do? Please show code.

Comment: looks like a job for regular expressions.

Comment: please note that buff points to a literal which must not be modified, use instead char buff[] = ...

Comment: You can't "remove", but you can construct a new string.

Comment: find the position of `<` and `|` with `strstr` and assemble both parts.

Comment: I have updated the question now.

Comment: Code cannot remove (without UB) the contents of _string literal_ `"cat –v <  x y z | "`.  Code can create (allocate) a new string with the shrunken contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative would be a simple function that iterates over the source string copying characters that are not to be removed to a destination string as in the following.

```
char *  CopyStringRemove(char *pDest, const char *pSrc)
{
    // copy the source string, pSrc, to the destination string, pDest, while
    // removing special codes that are between a < character and a | character.
    // we will copy the two special code characters but remove everything in between.
    char * pRet = pDest;

    if (pDest) {
        if (pSrc) {
            int   iState = 0;      // state indicates whether copying characters or not.

            for (; *pSrc; pSrc++) {
                switch (*pSrc) {
                case '<':
                    iState = 1;         // indicate we are skipping characters
                    *pDest++ = *pSrc;   // however copy this character we found
                    break;
                case '|':
                    iState = 0;     // indicate we are copying characters
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                switch (iState) {
                case 0:
                    *pDest++ = *pSrc;    // state is to copy the current character
                    break;
                case 1:                  // state is to not copy current character, just skip over it.
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        *pDest = 0;
    }

    return pRet;
}
```

This function provides quite a bit of flexibility in that the source can be a constant or not. The destination may be an array on the stack or an array malloced from the heap. If the source array is not `const` then you can do an inplace change by calling the `CopyStringRemove()` function with both source and destination being the same buffer.

It also allows for problems with the input such as not having a '<' character or a '|' character in the string.

A test harness such as:

```
void testfunc(const char *buff)
{
    {
        char destbuff[128] = { 0 };
        printf("    orig string \"%s\"\n", buff);
        CopyStringRemove(destbuff, buff);
        printf("        new     \"%s\"\n", destbuff);
    }

    {
        char destbuff[128] = { 0 };
        char buff2[128] = { 0 };
        strcpy_s(buff2, sizeof(buff2), buff);
        printf("    orig string \"%s\"\n", buff2);
        CopyStringRemove(destbuff, buff2);
        printf("        new     \"%s\"\n", destbuff);
    }

    {
        char buff2[128] = { 0 };
        strcpy_s(buff2, sizeof(buff2), buff);
        printf("    orig string \"%s\"\n", buff2);
        CopyStringRemove(buff2, buff2);
        printf("        new     \"%s\"\n", buff2);
    }

}

void main_xfun(void)
{
    char *buff = "cat -v <  x y z | ";
    char *buffa = "cat -v <  x y z  ";
    char *buffb = "cat -v   x y z | ";
    char *buffc = "cat -v   x y z  ";

    printf("\ntest #1\n");
    testfunc(buff);
    printf("\ntest #2\n");
    testfunc(buffa);
    printf("\ntest #3\n");
    testfunc(buffb);
    printf("\ntest #4\n");
    testfunc(buffc);
}
```

yields a result of:

```
test #1
    orig string "cat -v <  x y z | "
        new     "cat -v <| "
    orig string "cat -v <  x y z | "
        new     "cat -v <| "
    orig string "cat -v <  x y z | "
        new     "cat -v <| "

test #2
    orig string "cat -v <  x y z  "
        new     "cat -v <"
    orig string "cat -v <  x y z  "
        new     "cat -v <"
    orig string "cat -v <  x y z  "
        new     "cat -v <"

test #3
    orig string "cat -v   x y z | "
        new     "cat -v   x y z | "
    orig string "cat -v   x y z | "
        new     "cat -v   x y z | "
    orig string "cat -v   x y z | "
        new     "cat -v   x y z | "

test #4
    orig string "cat -v   x y z  "
        new     "cat -v   x y z  "
    orig string "cat -v   x y z  "
        new     "cat -v   x y z  "
    orig string "cat -v   x y z  "
        new     "cat -v   x y z  "
```

Answer (score 1):

I would generally recommend regexes for this, and certainly not `strtok`, and even less on a string literal (undefined behaviour, see [C's strtok() and read only string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272876/cs-strtok-and-read-only-string-literals?rq=1))

One solution with only basic libs would be to:

- look for the start string/character
- look for the end string/character
- rebuild a string (as long or shorter) with the part before the start string assembled with the part after the end string.

I'm using `strstr` for this. It's built-in, doesn't need a loop, and works for multi-char patterns.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  const char *buff = "cat -v <  x y z | hello";
  const char *start_pattern = "<";
  const char *end_pattern = "|";

  const char *start = strstr(buff,start_pattern);
  if (start)
  {
    const char *end = strstr(start,end_pattern);
    if (end)
    {
    // allocate enough memory
    char *newbuff = malloc(strlen(buff)+1);

    int startlen = start-buff;   // length of the start of the string we want to keep

    strncpy(newbuff,buff,startlen);  // start of the string
    strcpy(newbuff+startlen,end+strlen(end_pattern));  // end of the string

    printf("Result:%s\n",newbuff);
    free(newbuff);   // free the memory
    }
  }

}
```

EDIT: some code has been added to the question in the meanwhile. Which explains I didn't take it into account, as I was trying to write a not-so-clunky solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is (almost) not builtin solution:

- either you want to modify *inplace*: in that case you have to "move" the end of your string (basically `|`);
- or create a new string, copy the relevant part an skip what's not.